# Storyboard done, Do I need to create .h and .m View Controller file for each View created?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have created Storyboard with several views calling each other, now I need to create the code

I notice that XCode didn't created .h and .m controller files for each View from storyboard.

Should I create them manually? 
Should I keep only one controller? (or few depending of separation of concerns on MVC)
Is there a pattern for developing this?

thanks

Comment: Are you using multiple view controllers?

Comment: I'm using only one ViewController so far with multiple UI Views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach is one view controller pr. screen full of content. You can imagine having one view controller for a tableview, with any sort of content, and then another view controller that presents that content in a new screen full of content if a row is pressed.

Normally when you have subviews inside of your view controllers, you wire them up in interfacebuilder. Then for instance if you want to populate a view that has a uiimageview and a uiactivityindicatorview inside it, you can control their behavior and how their populated from the view controllers code. You could also if you want something very generic and you feel that one view will probably take up a lot of code in your view controller, create a uiview subclass for it, and then set the class in interface builder.

Did this help? Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your answer(I voted it up), I know I can do those things, but I'm looking for which pattern people use it if there is any

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely up to you whether you have a ViewController for each view. If you have many views I would recommend it. Even if you have 2 or 3 views you probably still should. Things can get really confusing when each view has a different task but all have similar IBOutlets.

**TLDR;** Personally, I would say it was good practice to have a ViewController for each view *if* each view has a separate task.